# SAML AssertionID

Tags: oracle, soap, saml, soa

I am trying to invoke a SOAP service using SAML Authentication token (Oracle EBS Integrated SOA Gateway). Testing it using SoapUI, when I am inserting the SAML Assertion there i need to input value for AssertionID, from where I can get this Assertion ID?
What will be the issuer?

I have keystore at client side (Desktop machine where SoapUI is running) and another keystore at the server.

SAML ASSERTION

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You generate it. It needs to be a [unique identifier](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xml-schema/0596002521/re74.html).

From the [schema](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/3408/oasis-sstc-saml-schema-assertion-1.0.xsd), it's defined as

```
<attribute name="AssertionID" type="ID" use="required"/>
```

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_1.1) gives a sample so you can see a traditional format

```
<saml:Assertion
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"
MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1"
AssertionID="buGxcG4gILg5NlocyLccDz6iXrUa"
Issuer="https://idp.example.org/saml"
IssueInstant="2002-06-19T17:05:37.795Z">
```

Comment: Thanks jefftrotman for your reply, I am totally new to it,  can you please guide me how to generate it ?

Comment: It will depend on your language. If you Google "generating unique ids" you can find some help. For instance, in C#, you could use Guid.NewGuid(). Here's a page I found via Google search for Java - http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56